# Chrome browser unable to create session with selenium grid. It simply hangs randomly for tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

What do i need to do to use the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS =/dev/null. I am using selenium standalone server with hub on windows machine and trying to use chrome browser of a mac. I have 70 tests for which hub creates a session on node , test steps are fired and browser is quit. So at times randomly at times for chrome browser session is not created and the hub has to wait until timeout occurs . Thanks

The following link https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87 suggests to set the above mentioned property but i don't understand how to do this exactly. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your .bashrc

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
```

and do the following in your command line

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```