# Chrome Driver Hangs intermittently while execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate my application, i have around 400 test cases to be automated,  i use jenkins for Continous Integration.

Every day i trigger execution through Jenkins as part of nightly executions, but after some time Chrome Driver Hangs, i cant see the browser. But in console log in Jenkins i can see

**"[launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running"** , i cant see browser and my execution can't proceed further and i had to forcefully stop the Build.

I'm using

Windows 7
Protractor 2.5.1

my sample conf.js file

```
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
},
'autoStartStopServer': true,
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
},
suites: {
    specs: '../specs/module1/*.js',

},
```

I found similar issue with a proposed solution [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099142/chrome-browser-unable-to-create-session-with-selenium-grid-it-simply-hangs-rand) it says to add `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null` but how to use the same in Windows, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In command promt (not git bash or cywin) try this command:

SET DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null

To set Environment Variables then run node app, try this command:

SET DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null&& node app.js